# How can I configure Jenkins using .groovy config file to set up 'Build strategies -> Tags' in my multi-branch pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I want something similar for 'Basic Branch Build Strategies' plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/basic-branch-build-strategies

I figure out to make it something like this but it's not working:

```
      def traits = it / sources / data / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' / source / traits

      traits << 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.TagDiscoveryTrait' {
          strategyId(3)
      }

      traits << 'jenkins.branch.buildstrategies.basic.TagBuildStrategyImpl' {
          strategyId(1)
      }
```

Here you can find full config file: https://gist.github.com/sobi3ch/170bfb0abc4b7d91a1f757a9db07decf

The first trait is working fine 'TagDiscoveryTrait' but second (my change) doesn't apply on Jenkins restart, 'TagBuildStrategyImpl'.

How can I configure 'Build strategies -> Tags' in .groovy config for my multibranch pipeline using 'Basic Branch Build Strategies' plugin?
[image]

UPDATE: Maybe I don't need to use traits at all. Maybe there is a simpler solution. I'm not expert in Jenkins groovy configuration.

UPDATE 2: This is scan log for my code https://gist.github.com/sobi3ch/74051b3e33967d2dd9dc7853bfb0799d

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following Groovy init script to setup a Jenkins job with a "tag" build strategy.

```groovy
def job = instance.createProject(WorkflowMultiBranchProject.class, "<job-name>")
PersistedList sources = job.getSourcesList()
// I am using Bitbucket, you need to replace this with your source
def pullRequestSource = new BitbucketSCMSource("<repo-owner>", "<repo-name>")
def source = new BranchSource(pullRequestSource)
source.setBuildStrategies([new TagBuildStrategyImpl(null, null)])
sources.add(source)
```

Comment: This is nice and clean. I'm working with the Bitbucket Branch Source plugin and using BitbucketSCMNavigator which doesn't seem to quite match the above objects/api calls. Have you (or anyone) integrated the basic-branch-strategy plugin with that in a groovy init file?

Answer (score 0):

If I am recognizing the syntax correctly, the question is about [Job DSL plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/).

The problem with the attempted solution is that the `TagBuildStrategyImpl` is not a Trait (known as Behavior in UI) but a Build Strategy. The error confirms this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: jenkins.branch.buildstrategies.basic.TagBuildStrategyImpl cannot be cast to jenkins.scm.api.trait.SCMSourceTrait
```

Class cannot be cast because `TagBuildStrategyImpl` does not extend `SCMSourceTrait`, it extends `BranchBuildStrategy`.

The best way to discover the JobDSL syntax applicable for a specific installation of Jenkins is to use the built-in Job DSL [API Viewer](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/). It is available under `<jenkins-location>/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html`, e.g. https://ci.jenkins.io/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html

On the version I am running what you are try to achieve would look approximately like this:

```
multibranchPipelineJob('foo') {
  branchSources {
    branchSource {
      source {
        bitbucket {
          ...
          traits {
            bitbucketTagDiscovery()
          }
        }
      }
      buildStrategies {
        buildTags { ... }
      }
    }
  }
}
```